# How can I delete an item from a list inside a object using room

Tags: android, android-room

So I want to delete an item from a list that is in an object on my db.

```
@Entity(tableName = "item_list")
data class ItemListEntity(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
    val posts: List<PostEntity>
)

@Entity(tableName = "item")
data class ItemEntity(@PrimaryKey val id: Long,
                  val userId: Int,
                  val title: String,
                  val body: String,
                  val isFavorite: Boolean)
```

But I have no ideia how to do that.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about how you're storing object? Like Are you creating Convertors or any thing else.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to delete a PostEntity from the posts of an ItemListEntity row, then you would:-

1. retrieve the respective ItemListEntity object from the item_list table,
2. delete the respective PostEntity from the retrieved object and then,
3. update (using an `@Update`) the respective ItemListEntity with the updated object (with the PostEntity removed).

- Accomplishing 2 would likely involve creating an alternative/new ItemListEntity object from the original, who's List would be the original/extracted list less the removed PostEntity.

**Demo**

The following is an example that is **loosely** based upon your code *(noting that the posts field is a PostEntityList object, which is a List<PostEntity to suit my limited experience with TypeConverters, the principle is the same however (more accurately limited use of Gson))*.

First the core classes (note the subtle differences used for convenience):-

```
@Entity(tableName = "item_list")
data class ItemListEntity(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
    val posts: PostEntityList /* changed from List<PostEntity> for my convenience */
)
/* Made up as not included in the question */
data class PostEntity(
    val timestamp: Long=System.currentTimeMillis(),
    val name: String
)
/* Added for my convenience/limited use of GSON */
data class PostEntityList(
    val postEntities: List<PostEntity>
)
```

- Item doesn't appear to be relevant so not included

The Type Converters

```
/* Would very likely differ */
class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromPostEntityList(postEntities: PostEntityList): String = Gson().toJson(postEntities)
    @TypeConverter
    fun toPostEntityList(json: String): PostEntityList = Gson().fromJson(json,PostEntityList::class.java)
}
```

An `@Dao` annotated interface:-

```
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(itemListEntity: ItemListEntity): Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM item_list WHERE id=:id")
    fun getItemLIstEntityById(id: Long): ItemListEntity

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun update(itemListEntity: ItemListEntity): Int
}
```

An `@Database` annotated abstract class that allows running on the main thread:-

```
@TypeConverters(value = [Converters::class])
@Database(entities = [ItemListEntity::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

Activity code to demonstrate that:-

1. adds an ItemListEntity row with 3 posts
2. extracts the ItemListEntity from the database according to it's **id**
3. uses the `logIle` function to output the ile and it's posts to the log.
4. uses the removePostEntityFromList function to return the changed ItemListEntity (less the removed post)
5. uses the changed ItemListEntity to update the database
6. Invokes the `logIle` function with the extracted ItemListEntity (now with the PostEnntity removed)

The code:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()

        val pe1 = PostEntity(name = "PE001")
        val pe2 = PostEntity(name = "PE002")
        val pe3 = PostEntity(name = "PE003")
        val ileId1 = dao.insert(ItemListEntity(10, PostEntityList(listOf(pe1,pe2,pe3))))

        val ile = dao.getItemLIstEntityById(ileId1)
        logIle(ile,"PreUpdt")
        dao.update(removePostEntityFromList(ile,pe2))
        logIle(dao.getItemLIstEntityById(ile.id),"AftUpdt")

    }

    fun removePostEntityFromList(originalItemListEntity: ItemListEntity, postEntityToRemove: PostEntity): ItemListEntity {
        val newList = mutableListOf<PostEntity>()
        for (pe in originalItemListEntity.posts.postEntities) {
            if (!pe.name.equals(postEntityToRemove.name)) {
                newList.add(pe)
            }
        }
        return ItemListEntity(originalItemListEntity.id, PostEntityList(newList))
    }

    fun logIle(ile: ItemListEntity, suffix: String) {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        for (pe in ile.posts.postEntities) {
            sb.append("\n\tPostEntity Name=${pe.name} TimeStamp=${pe.timestamp}")
        }
        Log.d("DBINFO_${suffix}","ItemListEntity ID=${ile.id} it has ${ile.posts.postEntities.size} Posts. They are:-${sb}")
    }
}
```

**Resulting** in (i.e. the Log):-

```
2023-04-10 09:09:18.656 D/DBINFO_PreUpdt: ItemListEntity ID=10 it has 3 Posts. They are:-
        PostEntity Name=PE001 TimeStamp=1681081758550
        PostEntity Name=PE002 TimeStamp=1681081758550
        PostEntity Name=PE003 TimeStamp=1681081758550
        
        
2023-04-10 09:09:18.667 D/DBINFO_AftUpdt: ItemListEntity ID=10 it has 2 Posts. They are:-
        PostEntity Name=PE001 TimeStamp=1681081758550
        PostEntity Name=PE003 TimeStamp=1681081758550
```

- i.e. PE002 has been removed

---

**Additional**

---

You could adapt the above to have it all done in a single Dao function and thus transaction and also be even more flexible allowing for the removal of a number of PostEntity's (even all).

e.g. for the above the following function, if within an `@Dao` annotated interface, could be used:-

```
@Transaction
@Query("")
fun removePostsFromItemListEntity(id: Long, postsToRemove: PostEntityList): Int {
    val originalIle = getItemLIstEntityById(id)?: return 0
    val newList = mutableListOf<PostEntity>()
    for (pe in originalIle.posts.postEntities) {
        var include = true
        for (rmv in postsToRemove.postEntities) {
            if (rmv.name.equals(pe.name)) include = false
        }
        if (include) newList.add(PostEntity(pe.timestamp,pe.name))
    }
    return update(ItemListEntity(originalIle.id, PostEntityList(newList)))
}
```

- the Int value returned is the number of rows updated. It would be either 0 or 1

If the Activity code were then:-

```
    //dao.update(removePostEntityFromList(ile,pe2))
    //logIle(dao.getItemLIstEntityById(ile.id),"AftUpdt")
    dao.removePostsFromItemListEntity(ile.id, PostEntityList(listOf(pe2,pe3,pe1)))
    logIle(dao.getItemLIstEntityById(ile.id),"AftUpdV2")
```

- i.e. the commented out lines being replaced by the subsequent lines (to demonstrate removal of ALL `PostEntity`'s rather than just the one). The result would then be

:-

```
2023-04-10 12:35:49.781 D/DBINFO_PreUpdt: ItemListEntity ID=10 it has 3 Posts. They are:-
        PostEntity Name=PE001 TimeStamp=1681094149667
        PostEntity Name=PE002 TimeStamp=1681094149667
        PostEntity Name=PE003 TimeStamp=1681094149667
2023-04-10 12:35:49.797 D/DBINFO_AftUpdV2: ItemListEntity ID=10 it has 0 Posts. They are:-
```

- i.e. all 3 `PostEntity`s have been removed (as pe1,pe2 and pe3 have been used to signify what is to be removed)

  - of course just pe2 could have been specified and only that single PostEntity would have been removed.
- note the `?: return` caters for situations where no ItemListEntity would be found, such as if `dao.removePostsFromItemListEntity(5000, PostEntityList(emptyList()))` were used *i.e. there is no ItemListEntity with an id of 5000*

The following erroneous attempts are handled (nothing done bar wasting time) without a failure:-

```
    dao.removePostsFromItemListEntity(5000, PostEntityList(emptyList())) /* no such ItemEntityList */
    dao.removePostsFromItemListEntity(10, PostEntityList(emptyList())) /* valid ItemListEntity BUT no PostEntitys to remove */
    /* valid ItemListEntity BUT PostEntitys that are not present to be removed */
    dao.removePostsFromItemListEntity(
        10, PostEntityList(
            listOf(
                PostEntity(666,"no such postentity"),
                PostEntity(777,"another no such PostEntity")
            )
        )
    )
```

- see comments for what is erroneous for each

Answer (score -1):

I did not have complete information about how you store data, but I think you can reach your goal by examining this [link](https://normanaspx.medium.com/android-room-how-works-one-to-many-relationship-example-e8a17531a3bb)